# Echoing value from array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Sorry guys this is probably quite simple but I've got really stuck...
I have an array - $forms which using var_dump looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
  'forms' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'form_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'form_name' => string 'another_form_to_test' (length=20)
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'form_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'form_name' => string 'contact_name_changed' (length=20)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'form_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'form_name' => string 'test_form' (length=9)
```

I am using codeigniter and want to simply echo a value from this array, such as the third 'form_name' - I've tried lots of different things but nothing works... I thought it would be:

```
echo $forms['2']['form_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 echo $forms['forms'][2]['form_name'];
```

Comment: downvoters please check and let me know what i missing?

Comment: I did not downvote.. But the key is should not be a string. Strange that the upvoted answer is identical.. Edit the key to a int for a upvote.

Comment: No idea other then the index being a string, could you edit it to `echo $forms['forms'][2]['form_name'];`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the first level of array

```
echo $forms['forms'][2]['form_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
<?php 
foreach($forms['forms'] as $form)
{
    echo $form['form_name'];
}
?>
```